# Passing in tags to Gradle cucumber task

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I know that we can pass cucumber tags to Gradle by specifying the following in build.gradle file:

```
test {
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
}
```

So when you run `gradlew test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @CDC"` it will only runs scenarios with CDC tag.

But my question is whether I can pass the cucumber options to the cucumber task. The reason I need to do this is because my cucumber task creates a JSON file after running the task, and I'm using gradle-cucumber-reporting plugin (https://github.com/SpacialCircumstances/gradle-cucumber-reporting) to generate a report based on the JSON file.

cucumber task

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = [
            '--plugin', 'html:cucumber-report',
            '--plugin', 'json:cucumber.json', //generates a .json report file
            '--plugin', 'pretty',
            '--plugin', 'usage:cucumber-usage.json',
            '--glue', 'hellocucumber', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

Running the `test` task in Gradle doesn't update the JSON file.

Here's the snippet for gradle-cucumber-reporting:

```
cucumberReports {
  outputDir = file('cucumber-pretty-report')
  buildId = '0'
  reports = files('cucumber.json')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add something like this to your cucumber task:

```
def tags = getProperty("tags")
args = [
'--plugin', 'html:cucumber-report',
'--plugin', 'json:cucumber.json', //generates a .json report file
'--plugin', 'pretty',
'--plugin', 'usage:cucumber-usage.json',
'--glue', 'hellocucumber', 'src/test/resources',
'--tags', tags]
```

Then you can run your task this way:

```
gradle cucumber -P tags=smoke
```