# Is There Ways to Split Cucumber Gradle Tasks Into Separate Cucumber Tasks

Tags: gradle, cucumber

I wonder if there is a way to split cucumber gradle task to invoke separate cucumber tasks?

Below is the depiction of what we're trying to do:

[image: Split Cucumber Tasks]

We do this because we need to bypass a limitation of Browserstack where for older devices we can only have maximum of 5 parallel threads for each test execution.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Would [tagging the tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60281332/4161471) work for you? Or have you looked at [setting the number of threads Cucumber can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65473008/4161471)?

Comment: @aSemy Thanks for the answer. Yes we consider adding the task manually too but we intent to try to manipulate the tags on runtime, so that tasks are gonna be distributed automatically.

Comment: You could try some of the solutions for [improving Java performance in the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/performance.html#suggestions_for_java_projects), although you would set values to constrain the performance.